# How to write [sp+local_variable] in radare2

Tags: arm, radare2

Hello I'm playing with my native android library, everything was going smoothly till now. I have problem with opcodes, i don't know how to tell radare2 to write str opcode with specifc registry,  and point it to stack pointer and local variable.

Details below:

Lib loaded via :

> r2 -Aw lib/arm64-v8a/libnative-lib.so

Before changes

```
|           ; var int local_ch @ sp+0xc
|           ; var int local_10h @ sp+0x10
|           ; var int local_18h @ sp+0x18
[...]
|           0x0000946c      e00f00f9       str x0, [sp + local_18h]
|           0x00009470      e10b00f9       str x1, [sp + local_10h]
```

Applying changes

```
[0x00009470]> wa str x1,sp+local_10h
Written 4 byte(s) (str x1,sp+local_10h) = wx e10300f9
```

Unwanted output

```
[0x00009470]> pd 1
|           0x00009470      e10300f9       str x1, [sp]
```

Output that i want but don't know how to get it (note the  "**+ local_10h**" label)

```
  [0x00009470]> pd 1
  |           0x00009470     e10b00f9       str x1, [sp + local_10h]
```

Comment: Did you try to use "wx e10b00f9"? Also, seems like your "before changes" snippet already contains what you are trying to write

Comment: Yeah "before changes" contains the output that i want because it is original state, i'm asking this question because i have changed it and now i'm unable to restore it. The command that you have provided works, but exactly as i wanted. However it pointed me in the right direction. I can write it by "wa str x1,sp,0x10".

Comment: @Megabeets. Thanks for help! BTW. I was hoping that "wa str x1,sp,local_10h
" will results in the same output as wa str x1,sp,0x10 (local_10h is a label for 0x10) but it doesn't work this way.

Comment: Sure! You are welcome :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So to make an order from the comments - you can do it by using two approaches.

1. Use the original opcodes and write them using `wx` which stands for "**w**rite **h**ex":

   ```
   wx e10b00f9
   ```
2. If you still want to use `wa` you can do this like this:

   ```
   wa str x1,sp,0x10
   ```

In general, handling function's local variables can be done using the `afv` command and subcommands. Execute `afv?` to see its subcommands:

```
[0x00000000]> afv?
|Usage: afv[rbs]
| afvr[?]                     manipulate register based arguments
| afvb[?]                     manipulate bp based arguments/locals
| afvs[?]                     manipulate sp based arguments/locals
| afv*                        output r2 command to add args/locals to flagspace
| afvR [varname]              list addresses where vars are accessed (READ)
| afvW [varname]              list addresses where vars are accessed (WRITE)
| afva                        analyze function arguments/locals
| afvd name                   output r2 command for displaying the value of args/locals in the debugger
| afvn [old_name] [new_name]  rename argument/local
| afvt [name] [new_type]      change type for given argument/local
| afv-([name])                remove all or given var
```

By executing `afv` you'll see a list of all arguments, and both `bp` and `sp` based local variables. For example, by executing `afvs` you'll see a list of all stack-pointer based variables. Use `afvb` to see variables that are base-pointer based.

After executing these commands, you'll see how these variable names were defined:

```
var int local_8h @ rsp+0x8
var int local_10h @ rsp+0x10
```

For example, you can see that `local_8h` is defined for `rsp+0x8`, and `local_10h` for `rsp+0x10`.
While debugging, you can use `afvd [var_name]` to shed more light on the variable.

Comment: I would add a small note about variable address, you can get it by typing:
 afvd local_10h  and it will result in the output like this "pxr $w @sp+0x10". 
"